# Configuring SAML Single Logout (Okta/NodeJS/saml2-js). What should logout response endpoint do?

Tags: node.js, saml, saml-2.0

I am using [`saml2-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2-js) with Okta. So far I am able to logout. It seem to work according to Okta logs. The question is what should the logout response endpoint do? I am refering to the one I specify under "Single Logout URL":

[image]

Its a POST with a SAML body. Am I supposed to do anything with that body? If so how and what?

Comment: It's by the saml2 spec that the LogoutRequest requires the LogoutResponse.

Comment: @WiktorZychla so you mean we will call LogoutResponse then LogoutRequest?

Comment: No, you call LoginRequest as you claim your logout works. They send a LoginResponse and in this scenario where you initiate the sequence, you can pretty much ignore it.